# Key Vault ID Does Not Match Key Vault's True Resource ID

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to resize an Azure VM, but getting the error below. The key vault is enabled for deployment.

The VM is in ResourceGroupB but the Key Vault is in a different resource group. I'm not sure how the Key Vault was ever associated with ResourceGroupB, or why the VM has made it some dependency to make any change.

I've been working with Azure support, but my tech is either more lost than I am or this is an uncommon occurrence. I'm hoping it's the prior. It's just not clear how to dissociate the vault from the VM.

I tried disabling the secret version in question but that had no effect. On instructions by the tech, I stopped the machine and now it will not come back up so I'm a bit desperate. Thanks for any suggestions!

> Provisioning failed. Key Vault https://[NameOfKeyVault].vault.azure.net/secrets/[NameOfSecret]/[VersionGuid]
>       either has not been enabled for deployment or the vault id provided, /subscriptions/[SubscriptionId]/resourceGroups/[ResourceGroupB]/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/[NameOfKeyVault],
>       does not match the Key Vault's true resource id.KeyVaultAccessForbidden

Comment: how did you create KeyVault?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I did not create it, someone no longer on my team did.

Comment: What region is the VM and the Key Vault in and what kind of secret is it?  There are some region limitations with Virtual Machines and Key Vaults being in different regions.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the VM associates the azure keyvault with the MSI, try to disable the MSI of your VM(you can enable it anytime later).

Navigate to your VM in the portal-> `Identity` -> check `System assigned`, if it was `On`, turn it to `Off` -> check `User assigned`, if it was associated with a user-assigned MSI, remove it, then refresh the portal and try to resize your VM.

Comment: System Assigned is off and there are no items under User Assigned

Comment: @clickatwill Did you resize the VM in the portal?

Comment: Yes, that's where I attempted to do it. The support tech had me stop the VM (in the portal) and now it won't start back up successfully. It's in a state of failure until I stop it again.

Comment: @clickatwill Is there keyvault related extension in your VM -> Extensions in the portal?

Comment: Per the message there, The details are unavailable due to the machine being stopped. However, I believe there is possibly an Octopus Deploy extension installed.

Comment: @clickatwill Check the arm template of the VM -> `Export template`, see if there is keyvault related information?

Comment: Yes, there's a parameter value for vaults_[NameOfKeyVault]_externalid and sourceVault and vaultCertificates within resources > properties> osProfile > secrets. The vaultCertificates value have the problematic certificate Url value from the error message.

Comment: @clickatwill Looks your VM was [enabled Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disk-encryption-overview), try to disable it with the azure CLI [az vm encryption disable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/encryption?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-encryption-disable).

Comment: Operation is not allowed when the VM is not running. Is this accessible in the portal?

Comment: @clickatwill Anyway, you need to run the VM, if you want to do that in the portal, try it in the VM ->`Disks` -> `Encryption`, remove the configuration.

Comment: That is disabled as well. Seems like most of these configurations are disabled if the machine is not running, and the error is preventing the machine from starting.

Comment: @clickatwill Try to redeploy the VM:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/redeploy-to-new-node-windows#use-the-azure-portal

Comment: @clickatwill Try to `Swap OS Disk` in the `Disks`?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/os-disk-swap

Comment: @clickatwill And just confirm the three options are selected in the keyvault access ploicies https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLT2W.png, and the related secret is enabled https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgzGR.png.

Comment: thanks for all your help. I wound up just creating a new machine. These errors kept occurring and I ran out of time to fix the existing VM.

Comment: @clickatwill Well, it is also an option.:-)